# my cat is hurt what do I do?

Tags: cats, safety, pain

My cats paw got stepped on and she refuses to walk on it, I spread her toes to make sure nothing was wrong but she start meowing/yelling so I stopped. She keeps trying to go around with three paws and jumping up and down off my bed. I don’t know what to do because I can’t drive and I can’t pay for a vet.

Comment: This sounds like there might be an injury, you need to get the cat to a vet.

Answer (score 3):

This *may* just be bruising. Or it may be broken bones and tissue damage that won't heal well unless treated. Cats really don't like admitting they're uncomfortable, so if this goes on for more than a few hours I would assume the cat is in serious pain and needs medical evaluation.

If you can't drive, call for a taxi/Uber/Lyft/whatever, or take a bicycle, or ask a friend to take you, or take public transit, or walk.

If you can't pay, call your local Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to  Animals or animal shelters or similar organizations and ask if there is a veterinary service that would be willing to take small payments over an extended time, or if there is any sort of charitable find that might cover you.